# como puedo realizar un array con esa informacion

Tags: java

En un censo se ingresan Los pesos de n personas en cualquier orden se requiere encontrar
•   Cuantas son delgados (0 a 70), gordos (71 a 90) y muy gordos ((>90).

Comment: Hola colega, para tu pregunta, quieres que al ingresar los valores (en este caso los pesos), el sistema te responda en mensaje, la cantidad total de cada clasificación o qué esperas exactamente como salida.

Answer (score -1):

Si entiendo tu pregunta, puedes implemantar algo como esto y hacer uso de un ArrayList ya que no sabrás cuantas personas se van a censar, despues solo recorrer el ArrayList y checar los pesos y guardarlos como en un contador los que correspondan con el criterio que mencionas.

```
public static void main(String arrs[]){

         Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

            int delgados=0;
            int gordos=0;
            int obesos=0;
            Double peso=0.0;
            int aux;
            ArrayList<Double> pesos = new ArrayList<Double>();
            System.out.println("***Censo***");  
            do{

                System.out.println("Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)");
                peso = entrada.nextDouble();
                if(peso>0){
                    pesos.add(peso);
                }


            } while(peso>0);


            for(aux = 0; aux<pesos.size(); aux++){
                peso = pesos.get(aux);
                if(peso<=70){
                    delgados++;
                }else if(peso<=90){
                    gordos++;
                }else{
                    obesos++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("***Resultados***");
            System.out.println("Delgados: "+delgados);
            System.out.println("Gordos: "+gordos);
            System.out.println("Obesos: "+obesos);
    }
```

Comment: Hola @JesúsPetronaCastro. Tu respuesta puede ser válida pero no se suele contestar a preguntas que no están bien formuladas. El usuario que hace la pregunta tiene que demostrar cierto trabajo de investigación y mostrar lo que ha hecho hasta ahora, cosa que no ha hecho el que ha formulado esta pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Primero, me gustaría sugerirte que ofrezcas un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en todas las preguntas, ya que debes mostrar un esfuerzo mínimo en resolver tu problema.

Dicho esto, quisiera responderte de igual manera y si estas aprendiendo POO sería bueno que dividas tu problema en clases (¡divide y vencerás!). Implementé una solución para tu problema.

### Persona:

Esta clase instancia un objeto persona, la cual tiene atributo peso.

```
public class Persona {
    Double peso;

    public Persona(Double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public Double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(Double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona [peso=" + peso + "]";
    }


}
```

### Censo:

Esta es la clase censo, que intancia un objecto censo, que alberga un Arraylist de personas para ser procesadas bajo los parámetros del mismo (grupos de persona por peso). Además se [sobreescribe el método toString](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) para imprimir en el programa principal los datos del censo.

Debido a que el censo es el que divide a las personas por su peso, es esta la que filtra a las personas en los métodos `getDelgados`, `getGordos`, `GetMuyGordos` usando [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Censo {
    private ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();

    public Censo() {
        super();
    }

    public Censo(ArrayList<Persona> personas) {
        super();
        this.personas = personas;
    }

    public ArrayList<Persona> getPersonas() {
        return personas;
    }

    public void setPersonas(ArrayList<Persona> personas) {
        this.personas = personas;
    }

    public void addPersona(Persona p) {
        this.personas.add(p);
    }

    public ArrayList<Persona> getDelgados(){
        return (ArrayList<Persona>) personas.stream().filter(p -> p.getPeso() <= 70).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public ArrayList<Persona> getGordos(){
        return (ArrayList<Persona>) personas.stream().filter(p -> p.getPeso() >= 71 && p.getPeso() <= 90).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public ArrayList<Persona> getMuyGordos(){
        return (ArrayList<Persona>) personas.stream().filter(p -> p.getPeso() > 90).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Censo [personas=" + personas + "]";
    }

}
```

### MainProgram:

Finalmente, usamos nuestras clases a nuestro favor. Permitiendo al usuario crear personas para el censo a través de [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) y filtros para [validar](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-validate-input-when-using-scanner/) nuestro ingreso (termina en cero y no permite pesos negativos)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Censo censo = new Censo();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double peso;

        do {
            Double temp;
            System.out.println("Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)");
            while (!sc.hasNextDouble() || (temp = sc.nextDouble()) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                System.out.println("Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)");
            }
            peso = temp;
            sc.nextLine();
            censo.addPersona(new Persona(peso));
        } while (peso != 0);

        System.out.println("Delgados: ");
        censo.getDelgados().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

        System.out.println("Gordos: ");
        censo.getGordos().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

        System.out.println("Muy Gordos: ");
        censo.getMuyGordos().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

    }

}
```

### Ejemplo:

Un pequeño ejemplo de la ejecución del programa y sus salidas.

```
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
5
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
10
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
70
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
71
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
90
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
91
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
85
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
120
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
-3
Error
Ingresa el peso de la persona (presiona 0 para salir y ver los resultados)
0
Delgados: 
Persona [peso=5.0]
Persona [peso=10.0]
Persona [peso=70.0]
Persona [peso=0.0]
Gordos: 
Persona [peso=71.0]
Persona [peso=90.0]
Persona [peso=85.0]
Muy Gordos: 
Persona [peso=91.0]
Persona [peso=120.0]
```

Comment: Hola @Rcordoval. Tu respuesta puede ser válida pero no se suele contestar a preguntas que no están bien formuladas. El usuario que hace la pregunta tiene que demostrar cierto trabajo de investigación y mostrar lo que ha hecho hasta ahora, cosa que no ha hecho el que ha formulado esta pregunta.

Comment: Estas en toda la razón, pero tome en cuenta que el usuario es nuevo, y me gustaría darle la oportunidad de revindicarse la próxima vez que formule una pregunta. 
Si respondemos de esta manera a todos los usuarios nuevos, se irán y se pierde el sentido de SO. (mi humilde opinión)

Comment: Lo que hay que intentar es que editen su pregunta y la mejoren para que aprendan como funciona el sitio. Si respondemos a preguntas así aunque sean nuevos se acostumbra la gente y harán preguntas del tipo hazme este ejercicio que me corre prisa... y es lo que no se quiere. Entre todos haremos una comunidad de calidad =)